# React Router Nested Route renders inside of parent route, how to render seperately?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am making a shopping page and I have products displayed. Every time a user clicks on a product, router should render the product page where all the info on the product will be.

I have my routes set up like this:

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
      <Route path="/products" element={<Products />}>
        <Route path=":productId" element={<SelectedProduct />} />
      </Route>
    </Routes>
  </BrowserRouter>
```

And inside of `<Products />` I have:

```
return (
        <div className="full-products-container">
            <div className="displayed-products-container">
                {productsToDisplay.map((product) => (
                    <Link
                        to={`/products/${product.id}`}
                        key={product.id}
                        className="product-box"
                    >
                        <img
                            src={product.image}
                            className="product-image-displayed"
                        />
                        <div className="product-name">{product.name}</div>
                        <div className="product-price">${formatNumber(product.price)}</div>
                    </Link>
                ))}
            </div>
            <Outlet />
        </div>
    );
```

And now every time a product is clicked, the `<SelectedProduct />` component gets rendered inside of my `<Products />` component?

How do I make it that every time a product is clicked, the `<SelectedProduct />` renders entirely? And not inside of it's parent?

Comment: Don't nest routes if you don't want them to be nested.

Comment: @KonradLinkowski I tried doing it without the nesting but the Link needs a fixed path, ie /products/name-of-product. How do I change the Link to dynamically add the URL based on the product id every time a new product is clicked?

Answer (score 2):

If you want `SelectedProduct` to be rendered on its own page then it should be rendered as a sibling route to `"/products"` instead of as a nested child route.

Examples:

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
    <Route path="/products" element={<Products />} />
    <Route path="/products/:productId" element={<SelectedProduct />} />
  </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

or

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
    <Route path="/products">
      <Route index element={<Products />} /> // "/products"
      <Route
        path=":productId"                    // "/products/:productId"
        element={<SelectedProduct />}
      />
    </Route>
  </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

The `Link` components `Products` is rendering are already using absolute paths so there's nothing to change for the links, but now that `Products` isn't rendered as a Layout Route it doesn't need to render the `Outlet` component.

```
return (
  <div className="full-products-container">
    <div className="displayed-products-container">
      {productsToDisplay.map((product) => (
        <Link
          to={`/products/${product.id}`}
          key={product.id}
          className="product-box"
        >
          <img
            src={product.image}
            className="product-image-displayed"
          />
          <div className="product-name">{product.name}</div>
          <div className="product-price">${formatNumber(product.price)}</div>
        </Link>
      ))}
    </div>
  </div>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
    <Route path="/products" element={<Products />} />
    <Route path="/products/:productId" element={<SelectedProduct />} />
  </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Answer (score 0):

it's weird that you are nesting a single product page since i don't think there is any ui that you are sharing between products page and selected products page but if you want to nested routes you need to pass `Outlet` component on the parent to for nested rendering.
you can look at the code below.

```js
import {
  BrowserRouter,
  Routes,
  Route,
  Link,
  useParams,
  Outlet
} from "react-router-dom";

function Products() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Link to={"/id"}>Product Link</Link>
      <Outlet />
    </div>
  );
}

function SingleProduct() {
  const { id } = useParams();
  return <div>Product Id ${id}</div>;
}

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Products />}>
            <Route path=":id" element={<SingleProduct />} />
          </Route>
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

if you don't want to share the UI than just use the above solution mentioned by konrad

Comment: I want to render the `<SelectedProduct />` component when the user clicks on a product, and I want to pass params to the `<SelectedProduct />` based on which product was clicked. So for example if a user clicks 'some-product' I want to then pass 'some-product.name', 'some-product.price' etc. to the  `<SelectedProduct />`. Is this the way to do that?

Comment: you could pass props to `<SelectedProduct/>` but I don't think that's what you want. react-router is used for routing the pages or nesting the components in page in react so i don't think you problem is with router rather i am guessing you are looking for some state mangement. you can pass props to `<SelectedProduct/>` but you can't do that in routes.

Comment: You were right, I managed to grab the data I need by using the id from the product and then searching my `data.js` until I found a match.